# enable screen mirroring on galaxy S7 (broken display + locked by sequence) with keyboard

Tags: usb-debugging, broken-screen, samsung-galaxy-s7, screen-mirroring

I have a Galaxy S7 device with broken and black screen. The phone is locked by screen sequence (pattern).

I would like to activate the screen mirroring on it to backup data, but it is not possible to use touch screen.
So I have bought an OTG cable to connect a mouse or keyboard to my phone.
The problem is that i don't know which steps I need to perform to tap the screen mirroring button on the top menu.

Is there a way to know the steps to do for this purpose?

Or, is there an alternative way to access on phone?

I've tried with Vysor software app, but it is needed that USB debugging is activated on phone, so maybe I need to know the steps to activate USB debugging via keyboard.

Comment: I assume "screen-squence" means that the device uses an pattern lock. If yes this is bad because an OTG mouse only sends movements and not absolute coordinates. Therefore it is next to impossible to move the correct path to unlock the phone without screen. The only chance is to trigger the Google password prompt after too many failed attempts.

Comment: @Robert yes, you are right. Also notice that because of pattern lock, I can't do screenshots to understand how is the screen in a certain moment. Also, if I connect the device to my PC, I do not see any file inside, maybe because file transfer is not activated too

Comment: USB file transfer (MTP) is not available on a locked device. You have to at least unlocked the device once after connecting it via USB to your PC.

Comment: I suppose it is not possible to unlock it, am I right?

Comment: Not totally impossible but very very unlikely.